# How to make sceduled task properly in django using django-celery?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I new to django and recently i add django-celery 3.3.1 to my project. I want to add some scheduled task using celery from django admin but i cannot enabling worker

my **init** :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

My celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'akses.settings')
app = Celery('akses')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

my seeting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',  
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djcelery',  # <-------------*
]

    
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Jakarta'
    
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

It Return me an error :

> Exception Type:   SyntaxError
>
> Exception Value:  invalid syntax (redis.py, line 815)

My django version :     3.0.3
python version : 3.7.1

How to make make it work properly?

Comment: It will be clear if you shar your code

Comment: sorry, i update my question